# Typescript: Precompile modify properties

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-decorator

I often encounter the following block of code, sometimes with many fields in a class:

```
// initialize the private, editable properties so
// they can be manipulated within the class
private readonly aSubject = new SubjectVariant<A>()
private readonly bSubject = new SubjectVariant<B>()
private readonly cSubject = new SubjectVariant<C>()

// make the the streams publicly viewable, but not 
// editable, so they don't get manipulated by accident
public readonly a$ = aSubject.asObservable()
public readonly b$ = bSubject.asObservable()
public readonly c$ = cSubject.asObservable()
```

is there some way to DRY this with a @decorator, while still keeping type suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep RxJs DRY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795469/how-to-keep-rxjs-dry)

Comment: @Shravan thank you, but no. this is more of a software engineering question about visibility, and less to do with actual rxjs, although it's very common with rxjs. maybe I should remove the tag. thanks!

Comment: @Shravan does the question make more sense now?